# Uploading a resume and sending an email displaying blank page in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

Having a career page where i will be filling the details and attaching the resume and sending an email once the user fills the data along with the resume displaying blank page.
Working fine if we are not adding upload resume option.

```
var $image_path;
var $image_path_url;
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->image_path =realpath(APPPATH . '..admin/images/blogimages');
    $this->image_path_url = base_url().'admin/images/blogimages/thumbs';
}
function apply($email)
    {

        $name = $this->input->post('fullname');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone = $this->input->post('mobilenumber');           

        if ( $_FILES AND $_FILES['image_path']['name'])
            {
                $file_name = $this->do_upload2();
                if(is_array($file_name))
                {
                    $error['imageerror'] = $file_name['error'];
                }
                else
                $data['image_path']=$file_name;
            }
            if(!isset($data['image_path']) && !isset($error['imageerror']))
           $error['imageerror'] ="Please Upload an image";
           if(isset($error))return $error;
        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'yyyy@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
        'protocol'=> 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
        'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'PASSWORD123', //$from_email password
        'mailtype' =>'html',
        'newline'  =>"\r\n",
        'crlf' =>"\r\n",
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $message            = array();    
        $message[] = 'Fullname  :  '.trim($name).' ';
        $message[] = 'Email :  '.trim($email).' ';
        $message[] = 'Mobile :  '.trim($phone).' ';


        //$message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
        $message = implode('<br>', $message);
        //send mail
        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->from($email);
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        //$list = array();
        $path = set_realpath('admin/images/blogimages/thumbs');

        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach($path . 'image_path');
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); 
            if ($this->email->send())
        {
           $this->flash->success('Thank you for applying to this post we will get back to you soon!</div>');
            redirect('apply');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->flash->success('There is error in sending mail! Please try again later');
            redirect('apply');
        }
    }

    function do_upload2() 
{
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'doc|docx|pdf',
        'upload_path' => $this->image_path,
        'max_size' => 20000,
        'maintain_ratio'=>FALSE

    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_path'))
    {
        return $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' =>$this->image_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
        'width' => 83,
        'height' => 83
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $filename =time().preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s.\s-]/', '_', $image_data['file_name']);
        rename($image_data['full_path'],$image_data['file_path'].$filename);
        rename($image_data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$image_data['file_name'],$image_data['file_path'].'thumbs/'.$filename);
        return $filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the obvious question here is: what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: It is displaying the blank page not getting any erros

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. Please read my comment again.

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: I asked about entries in your http servers error log file. I _assume_ that with "not getting any erros" you point out that you do not see any errors in your browser, though obviously I may be wrong there.

Comment: Any idea how to send an resume along with email attachments of users

Comment: Sorry, but either you are unwilling to answer to a question (why?) or you did not understand what I asked from you (then why don't say so?)...

Comment: In my error log i didn't see any errors

Comment: Are you _really_ certain about that? An http servers error log file _cannot_ be empty...

Comment: @arkascha i have checked my error log file in my codeigniter framework i didnt see any error related to this one  that what i am saying you

Comment: Can you tell me how to check that http servers error log file because i have checked in console,error log file and all i dint find anywhere

Comment: So what error log file _did_ you check? The one of interest is the one the http server writes. Its location is configured in the http servers host configuration with the `ErrorLog` directive. Typically somewhere under `/var/log/apache2/....error.log` or similar.

Comment: In codeigniter framework there will be a error log file for particular project i have checked in that

Comment: i am using xampp server checked in projected related error log file in that i didnt find anything about this issue

Comment: If you receive an empty page then a typical cause is that a script has crashed hard. In such a case there is nothing your framework can log, for obvious reasons (it crashed). That is why you _always_ need to monitor the log file one layer below.

Comment: Nothing? And error logging is enabled, not disabled in your php settings?

Comment: After adding the code related to uploading a file and seeting in email sending then only it is displaying like this else it is working fine

Comment: Then you will have to dive into your code and trace what is actually going on, so on a step by step base. We cannot help with that I am afraid, only you have access to your system. An empty page without anything often indicates a missing return statement or a wrong citation of values in a html template. But as said: we do not have the code. You will have to follow the trace...

Comment: Any one can give me the idea how to upload a resume and send through email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines for uploading images and files while sending email.

```
$config2 = array(
         'upload_path'=>'../admin/images/blogimages',
        'allowed_types' => 'pdf|doc|docx',
        'max_size' => 20000,            
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config2);
        $this->upload->do_upload('attachment'); 
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        $this->email->attach($upload_data['full_path']);
```